# Bootstrap columns are displayed underneath each other when using equal-width columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Using Bootstrap 5, equal width columns are displayed underneath each other for me. This is my basic example, taken directly from the Bootstrap website:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      Column
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      Column
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      Column
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Bootstrap (bootstrap.min.css) is loaded in the head and I can use all bootstrap classes no problem but the columns are displayed under each other instead of next to each other.
When I specify column widths like `col-xs-4` on all of them, it works fine:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      Column
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      Column
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      Column
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But the bootstrap website says I can just use `col` or `col-(breakpoint)` to make columns that automatically get the same width to fill the row. This just doesn't work for me. This is what the above examples look like:

First example:
[image]

Second example:
[image]

Note: Using `col-(n)` without a breakpoint (e.g `col-4` in this case) also does not work even though it should.

Comment: Something about your story doesn't add up. See the snippet I converted for you. It works fine.

Comment: @isherwood I have a local copy of bootstrap which I include. Do I have to include more files from the css folder than just bootstrap.min.css?

Comment: No, but make sure it's complete and of the current/correct version. You might inspect your column and one from a Bootstrap docs example and see if they match.

Comment: @gowner Generally speaking it is not as good or healthy to use local files. The CDN files help a lot with cache memory and they really do speed up your site a little more as well. So, just a test to see if it cures the current problem perhaps give the CDN's a try. You just need the link for Bootstrap itself and the CSS. With Bootstrap 5 I recomend using the link for 'Bundle'

Comment: @CuteCodeRob Replacing the links with remote files does fix it indeed. I'm still unsure of what I did to mess that up but at least it's running now. I'm unsure if I should delete the question or just leave it.

Comment: No @gowner leave the question in place. some of the point here is that from now on and the rest of time your question will help other people with the same problem. Really glad you got it sorted though, good work. I will add an official answer. Vote me up if you're having a good day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the links for your local files and instead try the CDN links. Above and beyond the problem you're having, the CDN is generally best practice for your website speed and for browser cache memory of anybody who visits your site.

Here are the links for the `<head>` of your page.

Bootstrap 5 Bundle (bundle includes Popper.js)

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

And here is the link to the CSS.

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

PS: The reason CDN should be your preferred option is - Imagine somebody goes to your website and your local files load into their browser. Then they visit my site and have to load more local files. If we both used the CDN then it is already loaded into their browser from your site or mine and wow everything is quicker.